# Applicability of economics, politics, and business tags

Tags: discussion, tags

When I look at how questions like these are tagged,

[Do corporations own human DNA sequences?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/12380/do-corporations-own-human-dna-sequences) (politics, health, dna)

[Do small businesses create the majority of the jobs in America?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2409/do-small-businesses-create-the-majority-of-the-jobs-in-america) (economics, united-states, business)

[How legitimate are the “support an orphan” organizations?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/how-legitimate-are-the-support-an-orphan-organizations) (business, charities)

I don't see how politics, economics, business do not apply to this one:

[Does food aid cause famines?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/does-food-aid-cause-famines) (nutrition, africa, charity)

Answer (score 0):

Two wrongs don't make a right... The other questions should be corrected IMHO.

Tags apply to *the topic* of the claim. The food aid claim is not about [politics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics), and not about about a [business](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) practice. It is about a claim regarding charitable donations to Africa and their supposed effect. We need to be careful that [politics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics) and [business](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/business) do not become meta tags.

Stretching the meaning, we *could* use [economics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics). However, the claim is not necessarily about the economy, but the overall effect. It is more of a "freakanomics" topic than classical [economics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economics).

I don't think [nutrition](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) is appropriate at all.

Finally [charity](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charity) should redirect to [charities](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charities).

---

EDIT:

- I've retagged the questions (your question correctly shows the old version)
- I've added they synonym - hopefully that's not controversial
- I've closed [one question from May '11](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3271/how-legitimate-are-the-support-an-orphan-organizations) that was off-topic to today's standards.

Comment: Beggars can't be choosers, so i replaced the food/nutrition tag with the economics one. It's related to, but not limited by, political practice, although the articles i find suggest that it's purely the long-term food-only help that's bankrupting local business.